# pass special characters from input to bash script

Tags: bash, shell, special-characters

I've a bash script that simple has to add new user and sign a password that is passed when script is called:

```
./adduser_script username password
```

and the password is then used as a parameter in the script like this:

```
/usr/sbin/useradd ... -p `openssl passwd -1 "$2"` ...
```

the problem occurs of course when password contains special characters like $@, $* itd. So when i call the script:

```
/adduser_script username aa$@bbb
```

and after script ends password looks like: aabbb (so the special charakters are removed from original password). The question is how can I correctly pass the original password with special charakters to the script?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably not in your script at all, but rather on how you call it. At least from the snippets you provide, it doesn't seem like the password field is being evaluated.

So, when you call the script, if an argument contains something like $a, bash will replace it with the value of the variable `a`, or an empty string if it is unset.

If `$` needs to be in the password, then it needs to be in single quotes.

```
./adduser_script username 'password$@aaa'
```

Answer (score 5):

have you tried strong qoutes ??

use  'aa$@bb' instead of weak qoutes i.e. "aa$@bb"

for example: check with echo command

```
echo "aa$@bb" will print aabb
```

while

```
echo 'aa$@bb' will print aa$@bb
```

In your script use

```
/usr/sbin/useradd ... -p `openssl passwd -1 '$2'` ...
```

now you need not to worry about qoutes while passing password as argument.

Comment: Hi, yes I try it that way: 

    `/usr/sbin/useradd ... -p `openssl passwd -1 **'$2'**` ...`

 
but it still does not work. Shell curry on removing $@ from the original password. 
Solution is to add single quotas to password when calling script (just like Jacobo said):

    ./adduser_script username 'password$@aaa'

but I wonder if there is a way to do it inside the script? Script is being called automatically with parameters (eg. password) passed from another remote system.


Thanks for quick response ;)

Comment: No, you must quote the password when you call the script as well. `bash` processes the command line (specifically, it performs parameter expansion on `$@`) *before* the arguments are passed to the script.

Comment: Yes Chepner, you are right. It should also need to quote while passing args. Thanks.
Gaspar, if answer is useful and solved your issue, plz check as answerd. left side of answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use double quotes with escape . 
For example: set password "MyComplexP\@\$\$word"

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing similar issue and here is my in take on it.
One thing we need to consider is the user of single and double quotes in our script file.

if we put a value, variable in single quote the value will be as it is and it will not be replaced with actual value we reference.

example,

`name='java'`

`echo '$name'` ---> prints `$name` to console , but

`echo "$name"` ---> prints `java` to console.

So, play around on which quote is best to used based on your circumstance.

Comment: This answer doesn't really add anything to the preexisting answers on this 7 year old question. The other answers have already talked about looking at different string types in bash

Answer (score -1):

```
/usr/sbin/useradd ... -p "$(openssl passwd -1 '$2')"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)